# Auto login in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

could any one help me how auto login works in wordpress.
Here is the scenario

I have built a site in wordpress (intranet) and is integrated with active directory.

Now what I want is when ever a person login to the system with his username (AD) and he browse to the site the details of the user should automatically come since he has logged into the system with user id it should not again ask for the user id again.

Comment: Did you try *any* of the results on Google, such as this one?  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22865/auto-login-using-active-directory-and-windows-authentication

Comment: If you use ./wp-admin/ rather than ./wp-login.php see if that helps.